# How to setup google goals for popup forms?

Tags: google-analytics, goals

My website has a CTA buttons. if i click "Request quote" button, it opens in a pop up window. After submission we will get a thank you page. Please let me know, how to setup goals in google analytics to know conversions? Should  we use event ? please let me know the steps to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Since you redirect submitters to a thank you page we can assume this is your Goal.

So in Google Analytics on target website profile settings > Goals > Create type: Destination goal

There You will only have to set the URL of your thank you page as the goal you want to check.

[image: Destination goal on Google Analytics]